# ANTLR4: Error message with complete offending source code line

Tags: antlr4, error-reporting

In case of an error I want to generate in my compiler an error message like e.g. clang, which contains the complete offending source code line.

Example:

```
1.c:3:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
    if ( x== y) { 
         ^
```

I have extended the ANTLR BaseErrorListener, but I have no idea
how to get the offending source code line (besides of the line number) as a string.

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple thing. You get line number and char position in your error info. Use that to locate the position in your input. Then scan back and forward for line breaks. The text between those linebreaks is your source code line.

Answer (score 1):

I created 2 methods in my extension of BaseErrorListener. One to get the source code line and another to get the '^' sign:

```
private String getSourceLine(String src, int line) {
    String currentLine = "";
    try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(src))) {
        int currentLineNumber = 1;
        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {

            currentLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            if (currentLineNumber == line) {
                return currentLine + "\n";
            }
            currentLineNumber++;
        }        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        currentLine = "\n";
    }

    return currentLine;
}

private String getPointer(int charPosition) {
    return StringUtils.repeat(' ', charPosition) + '^';
}
```

Calling them with:

```
    String source = recognizer.getInputStream().getSourceName();

    errorMessage += this.getSourceLine(source, line);
    errorMessage += this.getPointer(charPositionInLine);
```